# Coredns No SOA record for origin

Tags: docker, coredns

I have very little experience with DNS records or servers so forgive my terrible explanation.

I have a coredns instance deployed in my home networks docker environment.
I have a Core file similar to the following (I've renamed domains for privacy although if it's needed I can add them back in):

```
.:53 {
  forward . 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
}

docker.swarm:53 {
  file /root/docker.swarm
  log
  errors
}
anotherdocker.swarm:53 {
  file /root/anotherdocker.swarm
  log
  errors
}
```

Previously, the "docker.swarm" domain was working fine. However, after adding the "anotherdocker.swarm" record, things started going very wrong.

The anotherdocker.swarm file is:

```
$TTL 60
$ORIGIN anotherdocker.swarm.
@                   IN  SOA dns1.p01.nsone.net. emailaddress.gmail.com. (
          202101141209 ; serial
          7200       ; refresh (2 hours)
          3600       ; retry (1 hour)
          1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
          3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
          )
@                   IN A     192.168.8.117
*.anotherdocker.swarm.     IN A     192.168.8.117
```

Coredns is then throwing the error in the log of `plugin/file: file "/root/anotherdocker.swarm" has no SOA record for origin anotherdocker.swarm.`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks ok to me, does the anotherdocker.swarm file need a NS entry? How does it differ from your docker.swarm file which works?

Comment: That entry is me trying to extend a preexisting DNS entry. The DNS entry is publically available on netlify's DNS1.p01.nsone.net service. It has the registered domain of anotherdocker.swarm (obviously a different one cause I'm hiding the domain for privacy). I would like to extend it so anotherdocker.swarm resolves to netlify, but *.anotherdocker.swarm resolves to my internal network (won't be publically visible)

Answer (score 5):

the serial must be 10 digits. YYYYMMDDSS

Comment: thanks for this one, was pulling my hair out. Considering most guides say use datetime... I had 12 digits... now using YYMMDDmmss

...and yes I realise I'm leaving a horrible problem for someone to solve... in 78 years!!